# Why is my MLP always outputting -1 no matter what?

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

I need to take two dimensional input data generated uniformly from the unit square, and then label the data either 1 or -1 based on the XOR of two hypothesis functions, `h1(x) = w1^T*x` and `h2(x) = w2^T*x` where `w1 = [0, 1, -1]` and `w2 = [0, 1, 1]`. From there, I am supposed to run the data through a three-layer multilayer perceptron using the sign function for theta. For some reason, my MLP outputs -1 for all points no matter what. Where is my error? Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.uniform(-.5, .5, (100,3))
x[:,0] = 1
y = np.ones(100)
w1 = np.array([0, 1, -1]).T
w2 = np.array([0, 1, 1]).T
h1 = np.sign(w1[1]*x[:,1] + w1[2]*x[:,2])
h2 = np.sign(w2[1]*x[:,1] + w2[2]*x[:,2])
for i in range(np.size(x,0)):
    if (h1[i]<0 and h2[i]>0) or (h1[i]>0 and h2[i]<0):
        y[i] = 1
    else:
        y[i] = -1
print("h1:")
print(h1)
print("h2:")
print(h2)

#nodes 21 and 31 are just 1 with weights -1.5 and 1.5, respectively
node22 = np.ones((100,1))
node23 = np.ones((100,1))
node32 = np.ones((100,1))
node33 = np.ones((100,1))
out = np.ones((100,1))
for j in range(np.size(x,0)):
    node22[j] = np.matmul(w1,x[j,:])
    node23[j] = np.matmul(w2,x[j,:])
    node32[j] = np.sign(-1.5 + node22[j] - node23[j])
    node33[j] = np.sign(-1.5 - node22[j] + node23[j])
    out[j] = np.sign(1.5 + node32[j] + node33[j])
print("Layer 2, Node 2:")
print(node22)
print("Layer 2, Node 3:")
print(node23)
print("Layer 3, Node 2:")
print(node32)
print("Layer 3, Node 3:")
print(node33)
print("f:")
print(out)

error = 0
for k in range(np.size(x,0)):
    if y[k] != out[k]:
        error +=1
error = error/np.size(x,0)
print(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For nodes 22 and 23, the calculation needs to be inside a sign function, so the j for loop should look like this:

```py
for j in range(np.size(x,0)):
    node22[j] = np.sign(np.matmul(w1,x[j,:]))
    node23[j] = np.sign(np.matmul(w2,x[j,:]))
    node32[j] = np.sign(-1.5 + node22[j] - node23[j])
    node33[j] = np.sign(-1.5 - node22[j] + node23[j])
    out[j] = np.sign(1.5 + node32[j] + node33[j])
'''
```